# Oracle: DatePart must be defined...?

Tags: oracle

Any ideas as to why the following line complains that DATEPART is not defined as an identifier?

`IF DATEPART(v_ExpireTime, year) = 1899 THEN v_ExpireTime := NULL;`

It returns:
`Error(68,10): PLS-00201: identifier 'DATEPART' must be declared`

EDIT: Never mind, I found the answer. I now do:

`IF to_number(to_char(v_ExpireTime, 'YY')) = 1899 THEN v_ExpireTime := NULL;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already discovered, `DATEPART` is a SQL Server function, not an Oracle one. The alternative you've shown, `to_number(to_char(v_ExpireTime, 'YY'))`, will give you a two-digit value though, so if the year part of your date is `1899` it will only return `99`, so you won't get a match. You can use the four-digit year date format model `YYYY` instead of `YY`.

Another option is to use the [extract function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions059.htm):

```
IF extract(year from v_ExpireTime) = 1899 THEN ...
```

Comment: Cheers for that Alex. Oracle is now complaining that v_ExpireTime cannot be used as an assignment target (I'm guessing the `v_ExpireTime := NULL;` part). How should I fix this?

Comment: Different question, but... at a guess it's an `IN` parameter to a stored procedure? You can either make it `IN OUT` which might have unexpected side effects in the client, or add a local variable which is assigned the original value, and is reset to null in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct it is because DatePart is not part of the PLSQL Library so it does not know what you are doing.  The second method is for PLSQL.